# Mex file executing in series despite parallel compile

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, mex

I'm testing out a basic openmp parallelized code with a mex file. The trouble is that it seems to be running just one thread despite my direction to run it with 2 threads. Here is the code:

```
#include "mex.h"
#include "omp.h"

#include <iostream>


void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],int nrhs,const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    using namespace std;
    #define x_out plhs[0]
    #define x_in prhs[0]

    double *x;
    double y;
    x_out=mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,mxREAL);
    x=mxGetPr(x_out);
    y=mxGetScalar(x_in);

    x[0]=y;    
    omp_set_num_threads(2);
    int Nthreads=omp_get_num_threads();
    cout<<Nthreads<<"\n";
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        int ithread=omp_get_thread_num();

        #pragma omp for
                for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
                    cout<<"Hello! " <<i<<"\n";
    }
    return;
}
```

I use the following compile line -

```
mex -v paralletestmex.cpp CC=g++ CFLAGS="\$CFLAGS -fopenmp" LDFLAGS="\$LDFLAGS -fopenmp"
```

and in the verbose description the fopenmp flag shows up so I guess it is compiling it to be parallel.

The output I get is -

```
1
Hello! 0
Hello! 1
Hello! 2
Hello! 3
Hello! 4
Hello! 5
Hello! 6
Hello! 7
Hello! 8
Hello! 9
```

Showing that for some reason, only 1 thread is being created. This is a simple test for a problem I'm facing on a more complex code. When I run this as a plain c++ file without using mex, the same code seems to work fine.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!
Siddharth

Comment: you don't print `ithread` anywhere. Also openmp might decide not to parallelise your code if the iterations are too few (unroll the loop) and if you have only one cpu/core.

Comment: Hi, I actually initially did not have the for loop and i was just printing ithread, and that showed me only 0. Also, when I don't do this in mex openmp does parallelize it. I just doesn't do it for mex for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

This is an extremely common mistake: `omp_get_num_threads()` returns the number of threads in the current team. When called outside a `parallel` region, it always returns 1 since by definition OpenMP programs execute with a single thread only (the master thread) outside of the parallel regions.

The complementary call to `omp_set_num_threads()` is `omp_get_max_threads()`.

Also note that calling `omp_set_num_threads()` is a very bad programming practice when it comes to writing modules and library functions. The reason is that it fixes the number of threads for all parallel regions that follow and thus might affect other code. A much better way to do it is to use the `num_threads` clause:

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and comments. So I moved in the omp_get_num_threads() and the cout<<Nthreads part inside the parallel region, and did #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2), but that still does not change my output. It's still displaying N_threads as 1 and the output in that same order.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I did a fair bit of research, and it turns out that the CXXOPTIMFLAGS in the mexopts.sh file needs to be changed as well. So to the compile line I added:

```
CXXOPTIMFLAGS="\$CXXOPTIMFLAGS -fopenmp"
```

and that seems to do the job.

Thanks for all your help!